# Call accept_invitation_url in a different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to call `accept_invitation_url(@resource, :invitation_token => @token)` in a different view outside of the devise mailer and when doing that i got an err

```
ActionView::Template::Error: Could not find a valid mapping for nil
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:44:in `find_scope!'
```

Is it not the right way to do it? I just want to be able to invite users from a different view

Comment: It is the right way. You'll have to setup an invitation and `@token` first, though. Invitation is referred to as `@resource` in your code, but you likely will have to call it differently.

Comment: any resource or url that i can refer to?

Comment: Literally any rails book or tutorial. [Hartl's tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) is good.

Comment: i dont get it. I could find tuts if the accept_invitation_url is called inside the view of devise but i cant find any if the view is outside in a custom mailer view

Comment: Yes, you won't be able find a precise tutorial for every possible situation you may encounter. So instead of copying and pasting chunks of code from some tutorial, it will be much better to _understand_ what that code does and _how_ does it do that. You know the saying, "understanding one principle frees you from having to find a thousand tutorials".

Comment: `accept_invitation_url` is just a routing helper. If you give it an invitation object, it'll generate you a url. So if you can reconstruct how devise builds it (the invitation object), you'll be able to do this in any view.

Comment: u are right. I did pass @user object into it  and then generate token lik `Devise.token_generator.generate(@user, :invitation_token)` but it is still not working. gona see what is going wrong

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, so ya i found a way to do this. `@token, encrypted_token = Devise.token_generator.generate(User, :invitation_token)
    @user.update_attribute(invitation_token: encrypted_token)`

Comment: Great job there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way to do this.

```
@token, encrypted_token = Devise.token_generator.generate(User, :invitation_token) @user.update_attribute(invitation_token: encrypted_token)
```